# What is the relative pronoun "whose" acting as in the dependent clause

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm trying to understand how to diagram the following sentence.

"Teachers whose students are motivated happily work overtime"

I believe "whose students are motived" is a dependent adjective clause, with "students" as the subject, and "are motivated" is a linking verb with predicate adjective.

So far, I have this. I'm not sure what "whose" is functioning as in the dependent clause.

[image]

Comment: In what universe can a possessive be a subject?

Comment: In full, it's a subject-determiner genitive. It has "teachers" as antecedent, which is modified by the relative clause "whose students are motivated happily"

Comment: @KarlG Mine is one such universe. :)

Comment: In simple terms, "whose" serves as determiner in the noun phrase "whose students". Its category (part of speech) is pronoun.

Comment: Where did we get "whose students are motivated happily" as better than "happily motivated"?

How is "Teachers whose students are motivated happily work overtime" anything but ambiguous?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I agree that the sentence is ambiguous. I was working through some exercises and the question was to diagram that sentence, hence the post

Comment: That accepted, doesn't "Teachers whose students are motivated happily work overtime" reduce to "Teachers (happily) work overtime"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this as:

```
Teachers happily work overtime.
```

as the basic structure, with the adjective clause "whose students are motivated" added, modifying (describing) "teachers". It's a confusing structure because the reader can be fooled into thinking "motivated happily" are paired by "happily" modifying "motivated" (and by close proximity), but actually this is not the case; "happily" modifies "work"

It becomes a little more obvious if we compare:

```
Teachers whose students are smart happily work overtime.
```

Because "smart happily" makes no sense so we more comfortably pair "happily" and "work".

Comment: I see the same thing regarding independent and dependent adjective clause. My confusion lies in the word "whose" - I believe this is a relative pronoun that is introducing the dependent adjective clause "whose students are motivated". I'm uncertain as to what part of speech it is in the dependent adjective clause

Comment: @JakeKirsch You are right - it is a pronoun. "Whose students are motivated" is a relative clause. The term 'adjective clause' is a misnomer and best avoided.

Comment: @JakeKirsch It is genitive pronoun, whose function (in very simple terms) is that of determiner.

Comment: @BillJ - sorry, commented after seeing your earlier comment. I think I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This "whose" is a relative genitive pronoun.

In the dependent adjectival clause "whose students are  motivated", the complete subject is "whose students".   The structure of this clause is the same as the structure of the independent clause "their students are motivated".   Within these clauses, the relative genitive pronoun "whose" serves the same function as the demonstrative genitive pronoun "their", modifying the simple subject "students" by acting as a determiner.

As a relative pronoun, "whose" also marks its entire clause as a modifier of the simple subject "teachers".

I suggest the following diagram:   Place "whose" on a diagonal line below "students", just as you would with words like "these", "their" and "the".   Draw a dashed line down from "teachers" to "whose", just as you would to connect any other noun to the word that marks its subordinate modifier.

Comment: I'm no fan of the Reed–Kellogg system.  If you must invest (and if you can choose freely) invest in trees -- dependency, constituency, hybrid, or whatever.  They're not just currently fashionable; they're a significant improvement and they afford room for further improvements.